# How to configure IIS to allow HttpDelete without Removing WebDAVModule

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, webdav

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application which uses API verbs like `HttpGet`, `HttpPost` and `HttpDelete`. When App is published `HttpDelete` is not working.

While testing from Postman error is faced.

> HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

If I remove `WebDAVModule` from `web.config`.
It is working fine.

But removing `WebDAV` might give issue in distribution and security.
Is there any other way to fix this problem other than removing WebDAVModule.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could modify the webdev settings to disable the allow verb filtering.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Locate the web site which contain the issue and select the webdev rules

[image]

2.Select the webdev settings.

[image]

3.Locate the allow verb filtering and change the rule from true to false

[image]

Comment: I am using IIS in windows 10 and This still doesnot resolves the issue.

Comment: I suggest you could set this settings to true and set the request filter to allow the httpdelete and try again. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis).